# How can I create a RESTfull service to retrieve a json or xml file from a client

Tags: php, json, rest

I have to write a RESTfull service in PHP which can send json data to the caller and retrieve json (or xml) data from the user. I know how to send json or xml data, but not how I can get data back from the user.

Comment: Do you use an special PHP framework?

Comment: For rather small services I prefer not to use any framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is getting JSON data as POST or PUT body. To get PHP body:

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

and then decode json into a PHP object:

```
$requestBody = json_decode ( $entityBody);
```

If you are not sour the request body is XML or JSON then check Content-Type in the header.

Answer (score 0):

A RESTful api usually doesnt expect a "response" from the client.
What you want to do is to create an endpoint for the client to POST the specific content.

`/api/user/?json={...}`

On the PHP side you can retrieve the data with `$_REQUEST['json']` (which includes both POST and GET.

There is something called HATEOS that can be used for telling the client about links associated with the current resource (if you want to "chain" calls between the client and the service).